# A good way to storage/precharge energy for short bursts of consumption?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, energy

I have a battery powered application that must occasionally use a servo motor (like the ones in model airplanes, e.g. Turnigy TR-1160A). This servo will be used in short bursts of 1~2 seconds at a time, with a resting (inactive) time of at least 10s between usages, but typically hours. The battery is large enough to operate the servo for a couple of hours, but it cannot withstand the instant load (eg. >1A) the servo needs; although it could manage a continuous 200mA load without a problem. I cannot use a different battery, but I could add some circuit to storage (pre-charge) the energy needed for the servo, kind of like the flash system in most cameras. So, my question is: what would be the simplest (less component count) way to achieve this, provided:

- Output voltage is 6V; current is between 1A~2A.
- Current draw should not exceed 100~200 mA.
- It should not be too inefficient.
- It should have a very low power draw when not in use (<100µA).
- It should provide the output voltage in good enough regulation until depleted (a simple capacitor of course would not be good enough).
- It's OK to need a proportional pre-charge time right before each usage.
- Battery voltage is between 6 and 14V; a switched 3.5V regulated output is available.

EDIT:

Ideally, the solution would be an existing chip or embeddable module (even better!) with that kind of functionality considered (e.g., switched supply) and that needs minimal external components besides the obvious supercap.

Comment: SuperCap. | Consider small LiTO battery for peak load. | LiFePO4 peak current can be very high.

Comment: A battery is out of the question; I would need to keep it charged to prevent it from wearing out, and that would exceed the 100µA "inactive" limit or call for very complex circuitery. Supercap is the most visible option, but my question was more in the sense of e.g. is there a switching power supply with this kind of function integrated on chip that needs minimum external components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 amps for 2 seconds at 6V is 24 joules of energy and if this was provided by a capacitor the capacitance should be at least 5 times that required to meet the energy equation.

Energy in a capacitor is \$\dfrac{C\cdot V^2}{2}\$ therefore \$\dfrac{2 \cdot 24}{6^2} = C\$

C is therefore 1.333 farads but realistically it needs to be 5 times that so it doesn't become totally depleted during the time when the energy is needed in the 2 second burst. More like 7 F is needed. Make sure it's a low ESR type!!!

A problem occurs when the the requirement to drive the heavy load occurs too often. You said in your question that there might be a 10 second gap between "usages" and I infer only 200mA is available for restoring charge in the capacitor. 200mA at 6V for ten seconds is an energy availability of 12 joules and the only way around this is to have the capacitor as large as possible so that even if two "big demand" periods occur over a ten second period there is still enough residual change in the capacitor to service both requirements. Maybe go for a 14 F cap.

Can you get these?

Comment: I think you squared the voltage twice, which gave you an unrealistically low value for the capacitance required. You also slipped a decimal place somewhere.

Comment: Fixed dude - already onto it.

Comment: I could get a supercap, but I wonder if the usual 2x operating voltage safety margin applies to them (e.g., should I charge them at most half of their rated voltage?). There will be some important ripple current, I think.

Answer (score 2):

Supercaps and ultracaps are very good at supplying short-term energy needs. For example, a 30-50F capacitor rated at 3V would be more than enough to store the 24 Joules you need per operation.

In order to meet your other requirements, you would use a pair of switching power converters. The first one would be a buck regulator used to charge the capacitor from the battery. It would have a voltage limit that's a comfortable margin below the capacitor's rating, and a current limit that's set to 200 mA. Note that this converter would be a little unique in that you'd configure it to regulate the *source* current rather than the load current. This would minimize the recharge time by making the best use of the power available from the battery. Such regulators can have very low quiescent currents, but if necessary, you could put it into a shutdown mode under firmware control.

The second converter would be a boost regulator that can produce the 6V @ 2A that the servo needs, drawing its power from the capacitor. While the capacitor voltage itself will "droop" while the servo is active, the output voltage of this converter will remain constant. Again, such a converter could be put into a shutdown mode when not needed.